# A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Tags: wpf, exception, xaml, output-window

I have seen in the output-Window of Visual Studio, that there occurs many times the Message

A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

When I fill the DataGrid (Xaml/WPF - DevExpress DXGrid). Does anybody know why this is?

Comment: You should ignore first-chance exceptions.

Comment: I have performance-problems in my application - so my thoughts are, that this are performance-killers when it occurs so much?!?

Comment: The question is, if you have performance problems with the visualization or with processing/loading. Most WPF performance-problems with lists come when the list can not virtualize. Exceptions can slowen an application down (also first chance exceptions), but for this to say, there is not enough information and the reason will be found mostly in the higher levels of the app.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, first-chance exceptions are exceptions handled by the application (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx). I don't think you should ignore these exceptions unless you really know what's happening.

Comment: The fact that they are handled by the application is precisely the reason to ignore them. This assumes, of course, that your code doesn't "handle" exceptions unless it can do something about them. Then, all of the handled exceptions will be cases where the code is performing correctly. This is precisely the set of exceptions you don't care about (exceptions in code that works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx

Maybe this helps you further.

**Edit**

Based on your comment on your question, I assume, that you are interested in finding a bottleneck in your application.

[This](http://www.microsoftpdc.com/2009/CL11) link leads to a video I liked much to learn how to find bottlenecks in WPF-Apps.
The [WPF Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) is a free toolkit with programms to measure WPF-performance. It will help you to find the problem if it is in the visualization.